# Why was post placed on hold?

Tags: discussion

I suppose "on hold" means "about to be deleted". How is that helpful?

I was told that meta is the place to ask why my question was placed on hold.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946487/javascript-create-new-firefox-window) was placed on hold

Suggested I post elsewhere? Where should it have been posted? I looked over the Stack Overflow forums and I do not see an obvious place.

Perhaps I missed the complete list of forums. I looked at the bottom of the page and click on more at the bottom of the page. I there a larger list? An easier list to read the various sized blobs?

I've been programming for awhile. You 1) Write code 2) test 3) fix bugs.

Seems to me the program wasn't working, so that's part of programming.

Comment: You mean this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946487/javascript-create-new-firefox-window (from [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283662/why-was-post-placed-on-hold) on MSE)

Answer (score 10):

> It would be nice for someone to answer my questions, instead of down voting them. I do not mind getting downvoted, but please explain why.

Downvotes are feedback, generally meaning something like "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" (from the downvote tooltip). In addition to that, the question at hand did get several comments about possible issues with the question.

> What is going on around here? Now, I cannot find the question. It seems to have disappeared. Where do I see a list of all of my questions? I asked two questions today and I cannot see either of them.

Your profile on each site only contains the questions you asked on that site. To find your questions on Stack Overflow, you must be on your [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360075/historystamp).

> I suppose on hold means about to be deleted. How is that helpful?

Not at all! On hold means it's temporarily on-hold. Hopefully you will take the feedback and correct the issues (at which point it will go into a queue to be reviewed and possibly reopened). If that doesn't happen, or it is thought to be unsalvageable, then it will be deleted.

> This question was placed on hold
>
> Suggested I post elsewhere? So where should it have been posted? I looked over the stack overflow forums and I do not see an obvious place.

Assuming you mean [javascript create new firefox window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946487/javascript-create-new-firefox-window), not at all. The close reason does not say use another site, it says:

> "This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting."

Remember to read the full close reason.

> Perhaps I missed the complete list of forums. I looked at the bottom of the page and click on more at the bottom of the page. I there a larger list? An easier list to read the various sized blobs?

Stack Exchange sites are not "forums", but you can view [a list of them here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic).

> I've been programming for awhile. You 1) Write code 2) test 3) fix bugs.
>
> Seems to me the program wasn't working, so that part of programming.

Please read the close reason and linked documentation for necessary information when asking for debugging help.

Comment: There is not way of getting a list of all my questions on one page?  I seem to have lost a question I posted to day.  I guess I'll post again.  I'm sure that will excite everyone.

Comment: Or just go to your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1360075) and quick on the [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1360075/historystamp?tab=questions&sort=newest) tab.

Comment: Here is what the objection started with: "This question appears to be off-topic for this site."  Since it stats that it was off topic, I how was I thinking editing the question would help?

Comment: I want to my profile page. It doesn't list the three questions I asked today.  It doesn't list this question for instance.  Should I open a new question to ask about this? If so, where. (fyi: I looked at that list before, but no info, so I thought I might be doing something wrong. )  Is this really the compete list or is it only partial.

Comment: @historystamp This question we are presently commenting in are on your **Meta Stack Overflow** profile, not your **Stack Overflow** one. It looks like you haven't asked any questions on Stack Overflow today.

Comment: @historystamp You have asked [two questions on MSE today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215012/historystamp?tab=questions). Keep in mind that these are all different sites with their own rules for what is on topic and what not.

Answer (score 3):

Let's cut straight to the chase here.

The comments on your question indicated that **this issue does not exist in various browsers** or that **you are missing a simple declaration somewhere**, which would imply that that either the issue doesn't exist, or at least isn't reproducible.  Even on my machine I'm unable to determine what the issue is.

If you search a bit on Google with the error message `SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."`, you'll get a few Stack Overflow answers and a few more tidbits to help you figure out what's going on.  If those *don't* help, then you must endeavor to fill in *any* missing details in your question, since it's really not clear what purpose this fragment serves, nor does it make sense for one to blindly paste it into their console window without really understanding it.

Here's where you step in:  **you need to be specific about what it is you're doing.**  From what I skimmed, this SecurityError is Firefox specific and occurs when you're attempting to access a resource in a CORS context.  If you can fill in more details along the lines of what you're attempting to do, the potential is high that you can find a duplicate answer here.